# rotation of images in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, image-rotation

resizing images inside UIScrollView when rotating the iphone.

I have a series of images placed on the UIScrollView (some images are placed one on top of the other). When I rotate the scrollview at some page, the topmost image on the hierarchy is expected to rotate which happens but the image goes to the first page of the scrollView. Any help on what could be going wrong would be appreciated.

thanks
DKV

Answer (score 0):

I think the imageView which is misbehaving w.r.t to its frame is not added into correct super view. I think you should check that all imageView are added onto scrollView (if you want to show one imageView above another imageView make frame of both the imageView same, avoid adding one imageView onto another imageView).